Error de CORS en CROW
Tengo ejecutando un proyecto de visual studio con CROW para recibir peticiones http.
Tengo otro proyecto en node ejecutado en el puerto 3000 que hace solicitudes a los endpoints establecidos en el proyecto con CROW.
Leí y probé muchas cosas pero nada me funciona. Esta es mi configuración actual de CROW:

// Customize CORS
auto& cors = app.get_middleware<crow::CORSHandler>();

cors.global()
    .origin("http://localhost:3000")  //frontend host
    .headers(
        "Accept",
        "Origin",
        "Content-Type",
        "Authorization",
        "Refresh"
    )
    .methods(
        crow::HTTPMethod::GET,
        crow::HTTPMethod::POST,
        crow::HTTPMethod::OPTIONS,
        crow::HTTPMethod::HEAD,
        crow::HTTPMethod::PUT
    );

...

CROW_ROUTE(app, "/compile_and_run")
   .methods("POST"_method)
   ([](const crow::request& req) {
   auto code = req.body;
   std::string result = compile_and_run(code);
   crow::response res(result);
   res.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
   res.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
   return res;
});

Y esta la petición desde node:
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:18080/compile_and_run", {
         method: "POST",
         headers: {
           "Content-Type": "application/json",
         },
         body: JSON.stringify({ prompt: prompt }),
       });

Me da error de CORS y un 204 preflight
